# Can't convert object data type to float in pandas data frame

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, types, jupyter-notebook

reading an excel file in python jupyter notebook i'm trying to change a column datatype of a pandas dataframe from object to float and every try I get the message of ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Variable by base style'. What does 'Variable by base style' mean?

Answer (score 0):

the data you're trying to convert includes an item : "Variable by base style" which obviously cannot be changed to a float.

Comment: Looking at the raw data I finally understood, many thanks!